# How do I delete a person in my Google Hangouts?

Tags: google-hangouts

I have people I added during my Google class and people who have left the company and I wish to delete them. How do I do this?

Answer (score 1):

Open the last conversation with the person in your hangouts, click the configuration (gear) icon and either archive or delete the hangout. This will also remove the person from you hangouts list.

Alternatively, if the person appears in your contacts (http://google.com/contacts), find it and delete it from your contacts, will also remove from the hangouts list.

Answer (score 1):

You can hide that particular contact. In order to remove a person from your Hangouts contacts list:

1. Open Hangouts within Gmail.
2. Hover over the contact's name.
3. Click the 3 dot menu.
4. Select "Hide contact's name".

For more see the Hangouts Help [Hide contact](https://support.google.com/hangouts/answer/2945109?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en).

Answer (score 0):

The only way to get rid of unused contacts is to delete Gmail account. "Hide" does only what it says. Clicking + reveals hidden contacts, and all blocked & hidden contacts are still lurking at their menus.